# How do I add a new connection type to Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Looking at the plugin documentation (https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/plugins.html), it is clear how to add to new hooks and operators, but I am adding a new hook that requires connection information.  This information seems to be hard-coded in `airflow/models.py`.  Is there a way to add my own connection type to the list without altering Airflow's source code?

Comment: Why do you want to add new connection types?

Comment: I would be interested in the answer to this question as well. A use case would be, for example, writing operators which leverage specific API wrappers. I, for one, am willing to do the work to write the operators, but don't want to modify the base Airflow installation to add a new connection

Answer (score 3):

[airflow Connection's conn_type field allows null value](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/848e432865da82c86918bac8b466d17dc12cd84c/airflow/models.py#L625). so if you don't care about giving unique type name to your custom hook, then you can give a default connection value in your hook implementation.

```py
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session 

class MyHook(BaseHook):

    # ... impl whatever you want.        

    @classmethod
    @provide_session
    def get_hook(cls, conn_id='myhook_default', session=None):
        try:
            conn = cls.get_connection(conn_id)
        except AirflowException:  
            # create default connection. run only once.
            conn = Connection(
                conn_id=conn_id,
                # conn_type='string500',  # You can give new type string here. But no UI component's for you. Just leave it.
                host='default.example.com',
                port=80,
                login='default_login',
                password='default_pw',
                extra=json.dumps({...extra_defult_you_need...}),
            )
            session.add(conn)
            session.commit()
    return MyHook(conn=conn)
```